# AVAST 7.0 is not running with windows 7 ultimate

Tags: windows-7, laptop, anti-virus, avast

I downloaded avast 7.0 version for my laptop running on Windows 7 ultimate. After installing, when I started scanning my system it says

> Avast is not running please start it first.

When I started it is shows no reponse when I check solution from Windows it shows compatibilty problem. Can anyone suggest what can I do for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have avast 7 on my Win 7 and it works fine. Try to re-download it and re-install and restart (lol too many re's). If it not helps, try to install lower version and upgrade.